Can a Kshatriya put on a Urdhvapunda Tilak?
I read some where that Narada Purana says a Brahmin should wear a Urdhvapundra (for Vishnu) and a Kshatriya should wear a Tripundra (for Shiva). Does the Narada Purana say it is absolutely necessary?
I am a Kshatriya and feel closeness to Sriman Narayana, I would love to put on a Urdhvapundra on my forehead. Can I do it?
Please cite your sources.
Thank You!
Hari Om
